# Does seafile store synced files anywhere?

Tags: seafile-server

I'm using Seafile (on docker) to sync some files to a Synology nas and it is all working correctly.  I've created an external folder that is pointed to `/shared` folder in the container.

I think I already know the answer, but are the files synced to the server stored 'normally' somewhere?  i.e. If I sync a folder called 'photos' and it has 'a.jpg' in it, will I be able to find that file on the seafile server?

The reason for the question is I would like to backup the original files that are sync'd, rather than having to backup the seafile DB, etc.

(I am aware that syncthing does what I want, so I may choose to use that instead, just want to confirm my understanding)

Thanks

Comment: To add to the correct answer below: You may be able to solve your problem by using the [Drive Client](https://help.seafile.com/drive_client/drive_client_for_linux/) which can mount a seafile library to a folder without syncing it, then you could backup from there

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## TLDR;

No you won't find your `a.jpg` file on the server. Your files are going to be turned into blocks of bytes.

## To understand

If you take a look at this part of the [documentation of data model](https://manual.seafile.com/develop/data_model/)

> #### FS
>
> There are two types of FS objects, SeafDir Object and Seafile Object. SeafDir Object represents a directory, and Seafile Object represents a file.

> ### Block
>
> A file is further divided into blocks with variable lengths. We use Content Defined Chunking algorithm to divide file into blocks. A clear overview of this algorithm can be found at http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/papers/lbfs:sosp01/lbfs.pdf. On average, a block's size is around 1MB.

So backing up files will won't be as easy as making a raw copy of the `seafile` drive. As mentioned by @JensV you may still achieve something along those lines using the [seafile drive client](https://help.seafile.com/drive_client/drive_client_for_linux/).

Comment: Many thanks for confirming! The drive client mount seems like something that might work out. Thank you.